# Calculating class size for write

Tags: c++, arrays, class, winapi

i need help with something...I'm developing a simple 2D game and i'm saving the game map in a file with a struct written on it, like this:

```
void MapSystem::SetMapInfo(char* Filename, MapInfo* mapInfo)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(Filename, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return;
    DWORD dwSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
    SetFilePointer(hFile, NULL, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
    DWORD Written;
    WriteFile(hFile, (void*)&mapInfo, sizeof(MapInfo), &Written, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

And here's my class MapInfo:

```
struct Tile
{
    D3DXVECTOR2 Pos;
    int Id;
};

class MapInfo
{
public:
    D3DXVECTOR2 Size;
    int Count;
    Tile Tiles[];
};
```

My problem is:
When i use sizeof(MapInfo) it returns 12, i believe the compiler is treating Tiles[] as a pointer, and because of that it doesn't save the Tiles array, and even if i calculate the new size, like this:

```
DWORD newSize = sizeof(MapInfo)+(mapInfo.Count*sizeof(Tile))
```

The WriteFile function doesn't write it properly, anyone have a way to fix it?

Comment: How is `Tiles` allocated? If it is a pointer (e.g. allocated using `new` or `malloc`) you'll have to write the data it points to separately.

Comment: I just use mapInfo.Tiles[0].Id = 1, don't allocate anything

Comment: Where do you think the data is going? C++ old-style arrays don't allocate themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is invalid in C++. Using flexible arrays is a feature of C and can be implemented by some compilers in C++. But it is not a standard C++ feature. So from the point of view of C++ this definition

```
class MapInfo
{
public:
    D3DXVECTOR2 Size;
    int Count;
    Tile Tiles[];
};
```

is invalid. You have to specify the size of the array using a const expression.

Or use std::vector instead of the array

Comment: std::vector<int> MyVector;
 MyVector[0] = 1;
Why this keep crashing?

Comment: Use instead std::vector<int> MyVector( 1, 1 ); Or std::vector<int> MyVector; MyVector.push_back( 1 ); As for your code then your vector has no yet elements and so you may not use the subscript operator. There is no such element as MyVector[0]

Comment: Note that by switching to `std::vector` (which is a dynamically allocated array), you **cannot** write the entire `MapInfo` in a single operation as the `std::vector` contains pointers to outside memory where the actual array data is stored. You really should not be writing out the entire `MapInfo` as-is anyway. Serialize it instead.  Write its individual members one at a time in a portable manner, then you are not subject to issues related to data alignment, member ordering, pointers, etc.